# What is the expected value of the sample variance under a linear regression with omitted variables of an AR(2) process?

Tags: regression, references, autoregressive

Lately, I have been interested in phenomenons related to omission of variables. For example, it can be shown that the expected value of the sample variance under the inclusion of one variable $x_1$ but omission of one variable $x_2$ is $\mathbb{E}(s^2|x_1,x_2)= \sigma^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1} RSS_{x_1, \beta_2 x_2}$ where $\beta_2$ is the true coefficient of $x_2$ and $RSS_{x_1, \beta_2 x_2}$ is the residual sum of squares when running a regression with $x_1$ as predictor and $\beta_2x_2$ as outcome. Now, I am interested in getting a better expression for this when we have an $AR(2)$ process.

Let an $AR(2)$-process be given by $x_t = ax_{t-1}+bx_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$ (with the $\epsilon_i$ being independent and normal with standard deviation $\sigma$).

If we run a regression with $(x_2,\ldots, x_T)$ as the response vector and $(x_1,\ldots, x_{T-1})$ as the predicting variable, what can be said about the residual sum of squares? That is, if we (falsely) think that the process is an $AR(1)$-process, what can be said about the expected residual sum of squares?

Since I am quite unschooled in statistics (my only academic background is in mathematics), I would be interested in references (articles and books) as well as answers, even if they are only tangentially related to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice introductory book on the topic related to different aspects of time series models could be [Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387953515) by Brockwell and Davis among many others. Roughly speaking, the characteristic of the autoregressive process of order $p$ is linked to the *partial autocorrelation function*. Estimating the $AR(p)$ process:
$$X_t = \sum_{j=1}^p\phi_jX_{t-j} + \varepsilon_t$$

one common solution is to apply the Durbin-Levinson ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion) on the math of Levinson recursion) method, where the residual sum of squares of $AR(p) $

$$RSS_p = \mathbb{E} \varepsilon^2= \mathbb{E}(X_t - \sum_{j=1}^p\phi_jX_{t-j})^2$$

is linked to the $RSS_{p-1}$ as:

$$RSS_p = RSS_{p-1}(1-\varphi_{pp}^2),$$

with $\varphi_{pp}$ being the partial autocorrelations or the last component of

$$\Gamma_p^{-1}\gamma_p = {([\gamma(i-j)]}_{i,j=1}^p)^{-1}[\gamma(1),\gamma(2),\dots,\gamma(p)]^\prime,$$

and $\gamma(.)$ being autocorrelation function. Thus if you apply wrong order autoregression it will cost you in theory the $(1 - \varphi_{pp}^2))$, note that in practice the estimation error also adds here. In small samples it may happen that a smaller model $(AR(1))$ is a better predictor than the true model $AR(2)$ (as the parameters has to be estimated and they are not known!). This is also known as the parsimony property of a smaller model.

Comment: When you are saying $RSS_p = RSS_{p-1}(1-\phi^2_{pp})$, do you mean $\mathbb{E}(RSS_p) = \mathbb{E}(RSS_{p-1}(1-\phi^2_{pp}))$? It seems to me that the only sensible thing we can talk about is the expected value of the $RSS$.

Comment: @Har, I have updated the answer with the definitions of $RSS_p$ and $AR(p)$, thanks for noting to that, but note that here I use theoretical model and errors with known parameters, in practice you have to estimate everything, so the conclusion on the prediction accuracy remains. Note also that $ARIMA$ models are a-theoretical usually and lacks the interpretation, so the biases  in parameters due to "wrong order" are of least concern! Primary goal is the accurate prediction.